# Protocol buffer from bytes

Tags: java, google-protobuf

Отправляю массив байтов взятый из protocol buffer считываю их на входе через сокет на сервер приходит массив байтов с таким же размером но первые четыре байта заняты другими цифрами, выглядит это вот так.
отправляю

```
8, 0, 18, 0, 26, 20, 67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 102
```

а приходит

```
0, 0, 0, 71,  8, 0, 18, 0, 26, 20, 67, 114, 101,
```

впереди лишние и еще в конце не хватает байтов почему?

вообще дело даже не в том что отправляю protocol buffers данные, 
4 - ый байт указывает на то что размер должен быть 71(здесь не полный набор байтов) хотя отправляется 75 байтов приходит только 71, и все равно нормально раскодировавывается в protobuf, и зачем он так делает и зачем первые три байта просто нули

Comment: Покажите как распечатываете буффер, как его отправляете, как принимаете и как выводите

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Покажите саму структуру, как она описана в `.proto` файле.

Answer (score 2):

Немного погадаю:

> 4 - ый байт указывает на то что размер должен быть 71(здесь не полный
>   набор байтов) хотя отправляется 75 байтов приходит только 71, и все
>   равно нормально раскодировавывается в protobuf, и зачем он так делает

Что-то мне подсказывает, что 75 = 71 + 4, а 4 - это как раз первые 4 байта, которые указывают размер полезной нагрузки.

> и зачем первые три байта просто нули

Изучите вопрос порядка байтов (вот [шпаргалка](http://htrd.su/wiki/zhurnal/2013/10/21/big-endian_i_little-endian_shpargalka) от меня). На x86 используется Little-Endian, и запись для `uin32_t` будет такая:

```
71 0 0 0
```

для передачи по сети используется Network Byte Ordering, он же Big-endian, соответственно это же число принимает вид:

```
0 0 0 71
```

Comment: понятно что 71, это указывает на размер,зачем первые три нуля я не смог понять по вашей шпаргалке

Comment: Это 32 битное число. Дальше думайте сами.